# I am trying to upgrade 3.1.21 to 3.1.26,. during upgrading getting this error System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'

Tags: c#, .net

[I am trying to upgrade 3.1.21 to 3.1.26,. during upgrading getting this error System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFRL1.png)

Comment: `certs` contains no items. This error is the expected behaviour of `.Single()` when there's no items in the enumerable it's operating on. It's actually the difference between `.Single()` and `.SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.